# Sticky sidebar that floats directly next to content, inserted by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to create a sticky sidebar that floats directly next to my content column. It will be used to hold jump links on the page, similar to this [page](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/) but the nav buttons would be directly next to the content column.

The caveat is that the HTML for this sidebar will be added via javascript (this is part of a larger JS plugin), so I can't rely on floating the sidebar right next to the content.

I would like to use only CSS if possible. If not, the least amount of JS the better.

Here's what I've got so far:

### HTML

```
<!-- Main Section -->
<section class="main green">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nesciunt, dolores eveniet quia commodi velit alias consequatur asperiores possimus ipsum quasi dicta sit maxime. Voluptatum provident a voluptate sequi impedit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, temporibus, molestiae id non quidem vitae at placeat consequuntur in aspernatur incidunt officia facere ad odit harum itaque aperiam fugiat quaerat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, obcaecati, maiores, harum porro aut quidem ullam voluptatibus molestias perspiciatis fugit voluptas adipisci repudiandae accusamus cum deserunt? Quas, praesentium ipsam neque!</p>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Main Section -->

<!-- Main Section -->
<section class="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nesciunt, dolores eveniet quia commodi velit alias consequatur asperiores possimus ipsum quasi dicta sit maxime. Voluptatum provident a voluptate sequi impedit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, temporibus, molestiae id non quidem vitae at placeat consequuntur in aspernatur incidunt officia facere ad odit harum itaque aperiam fugiat quaerat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, obcaecati, maiores, harum porro aut quidem ullam voluptatibus molestias perspiciatis fugit voluptas adipisci repudiandae accusamus cum deserunt? Quas, praesentium ipsam neque!</p>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Main Section -->

<!-- Main Section -->
<section class="main green">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nesciunt, dolores eveniet quia commodi velit alias consequatur asperiores possimus ipsum quasi dicta sit maxime. Voluptatum provident a voluptate sequi impedit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, temporibus, molestiae id non quidem vitae at placeat consequuntur in aspernatur incidunt officia facere ad odit harum itaque aperiam fugiat quaerat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, obcaecati, maiores, harum porro aut quidem ullam voluptatibus molestias perspiciatis fugit voluptas adipisci repudiandae accusamus cum deserunt? Quas, praesentium ipsam neque!</p>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Main Section -->

<!-- Main Section -->
<section class="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nesciunt, dolores eveniet quia commodi velit alias consequatur asperiores possimus ipsum quasi dicta sit maxime. Voluptatum provident a voluptate sequi impedit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, temporibus, molestiae id non quidem vitae at placeat consequuntur in aspernatur incidunt officia facere ad odit harum itaque aperiam fugiat quaerat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, obcaecati, maiores, harum porro aut quidem ullam voluptatibus molestias perspiciatis fugit voluptas adipisci repudiandae accusamus cum deserunt? Quas, praesentium ipsam neque!</p>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Main Section -->
```

### CSS

```
.main{ background:gray; }
.green{ background: green; }
.inner{
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.pageNavigation{
    position: fixed;
    width: 25px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
}
.pageNavigation li{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: #ddd;
}
.pageNavigation a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### JS

```
(function sidebarNav(){
    sidebarHTML =  '<nav class="pageNavigation">';
    sidebarHTML += '<ul>';    
    sidebarHTML += '<li><a href="#">1</a></li>';
    sidebarHTML += '<li><a href="#">2</a></li>';
    sidebarHTML += '<li><a href="#">3</a></li>';
    sidebarHTML += '</ul>';
    sidebarHTML += '</nav>';
    $('body').append(sidebarHTML);
})();
```

## [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/KgKq4/)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you've basically got everything you want already.

You've got a slight issue in your fiddle where the fixed list wasn't showing up, but you should be able to fix that with a few styles on the `<ul>` element itself.

```
.pageNavigation ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

See updated: http://jsfiddle.net/KgKq4/3/

I can't tell if there is anything else you were wanting to happen or not? If so, let me know and I will update this answer as best I can to accommodate.

**Update**

The method for getting this sidebar positioned immediately beside the rest of the content may vary depending on your case.

In terms of the fiddle you have created it's a simple calculation:

```
right: 50%;
margin-right: -185px;
```

You push the sidebar to the center of the screen, then use margin to pull it back by half of the width of the content, plus the width of the sidebar, plus any extra gutter you may want.

http://jsfiddle.net/KgKq4/4/

If the width of the sidebar is unknown, you can push it in from the left instead of the right. This way, no matter the width, it will extend outwards from the point you want it to rest.

If the width of the content is a percentage and the sidebar is a fixed width, you have two options which will depend upon your required browser support. Essentially, you need to dynamically calculate the amount to move, so that if the width changes, the sidebar will move accordingly.

The first option, with the lesser support, is CSS' `calc()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Which can perform simple evaluations to figure out the required margin.

The second option is to do the same thing with javascript.

This second option also applies if the width of the content is unknown, and you have no way of calculating it. (This can almost always be avoided, however).

I'm going to demonstrate with jQuery because I'm much more familiar with it than pure JS:

```
var margin = -($('.inner').width() + $('.pageNavigation').width() + 15));
$('.pageNavigation').css('margin-right',margin+'px');
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Well I pretty much have what I want, but I want to have the sidebar directly next to the content, not hugging the right side of the screen. Literally pixels next to the content column. With my testing, I'm almost thinking it might not be possible with just CSS.

Comment: It should be do-able with just CSS, except in the most extreme cases. I've updated my answer, hopefully something there is relevant to your intentions!

Comment: Looks promising! I'll take a look in the morning.

Comment: Perfect! It really was so simple, thank you! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. Its very similar to the left 50% / negative margin page centering technique I regularly use. Thanks again for the help!